# how the recipient’s names are placed inside a bubble with X(cancel) button in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have implemented the compose screen in ios. In that for the To:field I want to implement a functionality when user enter recipient in To text field and click enter recipient name should be highlighted with bubble effect with X(cancel) button.

Any suggestions or examples are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to explain what you have so far, showing the code, and what it does wrong.

Comment: do you want to show a drop down of matching recipient names or do you want to autofill recipient name according to what the user has entered so far ?

Comment: I need to highlight the recipient name with x button.If user want to remove the recipient he just clicks that x button.

Comment: like To Field in gmail compose mail screen